# Unknown option keeplastbox for package `flushend`

Tags: texstudio, package-options

I'm working with a fresh install of MiKTEX and TeXstudio on a new Windows computer. On my other computer I can compile my article without error. But on this new computer, I get the error:

> Unknown option `keeplastbox' for package `flushend'. \newskip

If I try to use: `\usepackage[keeplastbox]{flushend}`

Here's a minimal complete example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[keeplastbox]{flushend}

\begin{document}

\section{Minimal Complete Example}
lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

I'm using TeXstudio v2.10.8.

Comment: The option has been added in version 3.0, released 2015/04/08, see http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/flushend.sty?r1=33669&r2=36753 Update your MiKTeX distribution.

Comment: Can you provide the steps to complete an update in a link/answer?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation?s=1|0.9855